# How to display count of results when filter feature layout ArcGis with javascript

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have multiple layouts in one project defined in object like this:

```
const layersByYears = [ 
    { year: 1918, layers: [ 
        { layerID: "443709212b894e9297888b3194b51100", opacity: 1.0, name: "ORP", featureLayer: null },
        { layerID: "61a605dca69c4aa0ac1b3858ba328fd3", opacity: 1.0, name: "obceSouc", featureLayer: null }
    ] },
    { year: 1936, layers: [ 
        { layerID: "a2e007238e304f1ea58005fc69c921e9", opacity: 1.0, name: "ORP", featureLayer: null },
        { layerID: "61a605dca69c4aa0ac1b3858ba328fd3", opacity: 1.0, name: "obceSouc", featureLayer: null }
    ] },
    { year: 1950, layers: [ 
        { layerID: "23bcd52310854d6185e5f22a4eca0303", opacity: 1.0, name: "ORP", featureLayer: null },
        { layerID: "61a605dca69c4aa0ac1b3858ba328fd3", opacity: 1.0, name: "obceSouc", featureLayer: null }
    ] },
    { year: 1981, layers: [ 
        { layerID: "401e9530ba074936800a8f596fc49d70", opacity: 1.0, name: "ORP", featureLayer: null },
        { layerID: "61a605dca69c4aa0ac1b3858ba328fd3", opacity: 1.0, name: "obceSouc", featureLayer: null }
    ] },    
]
```

Then I create variable to setup all layers:

```
const createFL = (layer) => {
        if(layer.featureLayer !== null && layer.featureLayer !== undefined)
            return;

        layer.featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({ portalItem: {
            id: layer.layerID,
            opacity: layer.opacity !== undefined ? layer.opacity : 1.0,
            visible: false,
        } })

        layer.featureLayer.load().then(function() {
            $("loadingProgressbar").value = ++loadingProgress.value;
            $("loadingProgressbar").max = loadingProgress.max;
            if(loadingProgress.max === loadingProgress.value)
                $("loadingProgressbar").style.display = "none";
        });
    }
```

Finally I provide filter like this:

```
function doQuery() {
    var selModul = document.getElementById("jevSelect");
    var attributeName = selModul.options[selModul.selectedIndex].value;
    

    const expressionSign = document.getElementById("signSelect");
    
    var selJev = document.getElementById("jevSelect");
    var inputValue = selJev.options[selJev.selectedIndex].text;

    let expression;
        
    expression = `${attributeName}${expressionSign.value}'${inputValue}'`;
        document.getElementById("printResults").innerHTML = expression;

        layersByYears.forEach(layerByYear =>
            layerByYear.layers.forEach(layer => {
                layer.featureLayer.definitionExpression = expression;   
            })
        )
        
    }
```

What I need is to display count of results (number) on each filter as label on point in map.
Project is here [map project](https://www.pramenykrkonos.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/index-8.html) - the problem is in year 1936.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to count how many features you get each time you set a new expression?

Comment: @cabesuon yes exactly and then display it as a label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the count of features that complied to the condition, you can use just a count query using for example `queryFeatureCount` method of `FeatureLayer` ([ArcGIS JS API - FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#queryFeatureCount)). In your case you could add an extra property to your structure, `count` for example and fill it each time you change the definition expression, something like this,

```
const layerQueryFeatureCount = function (layer, where) {
    if (!where) {
        where = "1==1";
    }
    layer.featureLayer.queryFeatureCount(new Query({where})).then(
        function (results) {
            layer.count = results;
            console.log(`${layer.name}: ${where} (count=${results})`);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            layer.count = "-";
            console.log(`${layer.name}: ${where} (count=${error})`);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. May I ask where should I put this code and how I should call it (call the const layerQueryFeatureCount)? I put it to the doQuery function but nothing happens.

Comment: You have to add it whenever you do a query, in your case at the start and then in `doQuery`. You also need to display the information, for that you could add extra code to the function above in order to show layer.count when updated. The function above only change the value does not display it to the user as a label or similar like you want.